# Use one output of epic as another input of epic in react observable

Tags: javascript, react-native, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using react-observable to develop a react-native application.

I have two epics, one is used to fetch the latitude and longitude, and another is used to get the address through the latitude and longitude.

My question is, as I want to do one thing in one epic, how could I use the first epic's output as the second epic's input?

```js
const getLocationEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType('GET_LOCATION')
        .mergeMap(() =>
            currentPosition$()
                .map(data => ({
                    type: 'GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS',
                    data: {"latitude": data.coords.latitude, "longitude": data.coords.longitude}
                }))
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("GET POSITION ERR", error);
                    return Observable.of({type: 'GET_POSITION_ERROR', error: error});
                })
        );
```

```js
const getAddressEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType('GET_ADDRESS')
        .switchMap(action =>
            ajax(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}`)
                .map(data => (data))
                .do({
                    next: data => {
                        console.log("address data");
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                })
                .map(data => ({
                    type: 'GET_POSITION_SUCCESS', data: data.response.results[0].formatted_address
                }))
                .mergeMap(() =>
                    currentPosition$()
                        .map(data => ({
                            type: 'GET_ADDRESS_SUCCESS',
                            data: {"latitude": data.coords.latitude, "longitude": data.coords.longitude}
                        }))
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log("GET_ADDRESS_ERROR", error);
                            return Observable.of({type: 'GET_ADDRESS_ERROR', error: error});
                        })
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be something like this:

```js
getLocationEpic(action)
    .mergeMap( (action) => getAddressEpic(action) )
    .subscribe( (data) => {
        /* get the result from epic 1 to epic 2 */
    })
```

Detail: Take result of `getLocationEpic`, then flatten it and feed the result into `getAddressEpic`. Subscribe on it for the final result.

Answer (score 0):

In redux-observable your epics receive a stream of all actions dispatched--what may not be obvious is that includes actions dispatched by other epics. This is a very powerful feature because you can write epics that don't need to be coupled to implementation details in the other epics. The action is the contract.

In your case, you said you want to sequence them as 1. get longitude/latitude 2. then use that long/lat to get their address.

Your `getAddressEpic` then just needs to listen for `GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS` to be notified and receive the long/lat values.

```js
const getAddressEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType('GET_LOCATION_SUCCESS') // <--- listen for location success action
        .switchMap(action =>
            // you can now use the long/lat from that action
            ajax(`${apiURL}/geocode/json?latlng=${action.data.latitude},${action.data.longitude}`)
```

Comment: Hey there. Did this answer your question?